# How to achieve the reverse of "attr.asdict(MyObject)" using Python module 'attrs'

Tags: python, attributes, python-attrs

In [documentation](https://attrs.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) of Python module `attrs` [stated](https://attrs.readthedocs.io/en/stable/examples.html#converting-to-collections-types) that there is a method to convert attributes’ class into dictionary representation:

**Example:**

```
>>> @attr.s
... class Coordinates(object):
...     x = attr.ib()
...     y = attr.ib()
...
>>> attr.asdict(Coordinates(x=1, y=2))
{'x': 1, 'y': 2}
```

How can I achieve the opposite, instantiating the `Coordinates` from its valid dictionary representation without boilerplate and with the joy of the `attrs` module?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Apparently as easy as using dictionary unpacking ([double star](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36901/what-does-double-star-and-star-do-for-parameters)) operator in corresponding `attrs` class instantiation.

**Example:**

```
>>> Coordinates(**{'x': 1, 'y': 2})
Coordinates(x=1, y=2)
```

Comment: This will work only if your class is flat and has no nested complex types.

Answer (score 11):

As a more universal solution, which works with attrs nested classes, enums or any other type annotated structures you can use https://github.com/Tinche/cattrs. It also supports structure/unstructure customization by defining the structure/unstructure hooks

Example:

```
import attr, cattr
   
@attr.s(slots=True, frozen=True)  # It works with normal classes too.
class C:
        a = attr.ib()
        b = attr.ib()
    
instance = C(1, 'a')
cattr.unstructure(instance)
# {'a': 1, 'b': 'a'}
cattr.structure({'a': 1, 'b': 'a'}, C)
# C(a=1, b='a')
```

Answer (score 3):

I do this in my web app to be able to serialize/de-serialize into JSON:

First I made a method on my classes that returns a more serializing friendly version:

```
def asdict(self, serializable=True):
    if serializable:
        as_dict['type'] = self.__class__.__name__
        return as_dict
    else:
        return attr.asdict(self)
```

Then when I need to convert one of these dictionaries (JSON objects actually) back into a class instance:

```
obj_type = values.pop('type')
if obj_type in obj_list:
    obj = getattr(sys.modules[__name__], obj_type)(**values)
```

Comment: As far as I understand, your solution requires an additional state that will carry the type name? Also, it is not clear to what classes do you refer to by saying: “_I made a method on my classes_.” Either way, I receive only python dictionaries I cannot modify but can expect concrete keys to model it into simple DTO for more comfort further usage.

Comment: Also, @patrick-shechetin you can make a generic method for dynamic creation of your **attrs** DTOs from your JSON dictionaries. Even more, if you have a JSON schema for them you don’t need to carry a type name in payload itself. As long as you can ensure your dictionary validates against the schema of a concrete type. You can find more in my other [Q/A](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45770755/7598113) regarding _JSL_ and _attrs_.