# How to materialize attrs data class from JSON schema defined by JSL document

Tags: python-3.x, dsl, jsonschema, dto

Assuming you using Python [JSL](https://jsl.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorial.html#introduction) library for defining [JSON schema](http://json-schema.org/documentation.html) of your data and you using [attrs](https://attrs.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) library for quick definition of your [DTO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_transfer_object).

How can you easily validate data structure against its JSON schema definition (as `jsl.Document` class) and reify it into *attrs* instance conforming to its JSL definition without extra boilerplate?

Because creating JSL documents and duplicate their definitions just to have a corresponding *attrs* DTO doesn’t feel to be the right way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define a function to consume JSL type for validation with actual data and once dictionary validates against schema collect JSL document attributes and use [`make_class`](http://www.attrs.org/en/stable/examples.html?highlight=goodies#other-goodies) method to produce **attrs** instance dynamically.

Here is proof of concept for Python 3.6.1:

```
from typing import TypeVar, Type

import attr
import jsl
import jsonschema


class Demo(jsl.Document):
    """
    Demo schema
    """
    ip = jsl.IPv4Field(required=True)
    """IPv4 address string"""
    headers = jsl.DictField(required=True,
                            min_properties=1,
                            additional_properties=jsl.StringField())
    """Dictionary of HTTP headers"""
    email = jsl.EmailField()
    """Optional User email"""


T = TypeVar('T')  # Nice hack using generic type hinting. It preserves auto-completion


def reify(schema: Type[T], data: dict) -> T:
    """
    Consumes JSON schema (as jsl.Document object) with dictionary data for validation
    and if data is valid then “attrs” instance is produced having same structure
    as schema object with populated data.

    :param T schema: Schema type (as jsl.Document type.)
    :param dict data: Data dictionary for validation against **schema**.
    :return: Schema transformed into equivalent **attrs** instance with populated
    **data**.
    :rtype: T
    :raises: ValueError — When **data** does not conforms with **schema**.
    """
    try:
        jsonschema.validate(data, schema.get_schema())
        props = [name for name, _ in schema.get_schema()['properties'].items()]
        fields = {key: attr.ib(default=None) for key in props}
        # noinspection PyTypeChecker
        return attr.make_class(schema.__name__, fields)(**data)
    except jsonschema.ValidationError as e:
        raise ValueError(f'Payload does not conform to JSON schema: {e.message}')


demo = reify(Demo, {'ip': '1.2.3.4', 'headers': {'Accept': '*/*'}})

print(demo)
print(f"{demo.ip} Headers: {demo.headers} Email {demo.email}")

# Prints:
# Demo(ip='1.2.3.4', headers={'Accept': '*/*'}, email=None)
# 1.2.3.4 Headers: {'Accept': '*/*'} Email None
```

As a nice bonus, PyCharm will infer correct auto-completion preserving documentation from JSL document class.